# How to use a 'Container View' in iOS? (storyboard)

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

i want to use a container view in story board project with mono touch and i don't know good objective c have a lot of sample but i couldn't understand.

[image: here i want to do]

thanks a lot

i have 4 view controller on my project and one customseque
i don't know how to call first view controller in main view controller

i try to put some codes in container view controller but couldn't success please help me from where i have to call and which code will call it - please xamarin code ..

Comment: Here's my explanation: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_storyboards_and_custom_container_view_controllers

Comment: And if you don't know what a container view controller _is_, see two sections previous: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_container_view_controllers

Answer (score 3):

i solved my problem like this.. thanks by the way who is viewed this question..

```
public override void PrepareForSegue (UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
    {
        base.PrepareForSegue (segue, sender);
        if (segue.Identifier == SegueIdentifierFirst)  {
            var a = segue.DestinationViewController as FirstViewController;
            firstViewController = a;
        }

        if (segue.Identifier == SegueIdentifierSecond) {
            var b = segue.DestinationViewController as SecondViewController;
            secondViewController = b;
        }

        if (segue.Identifier == SegueIdentifierFirst) {
            if (this.ChildViewControllers.Length > 0) {
                this.swapFromViewController (this.ChildViewControllers [0], this.firstViewController);

            } else {

                this.AddChildViewController(firstViewController);
                UIView destView = ((UIViewController)firstViewController).View;
                destView.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight;
                destView.Frame = new RectangleF(0, 0, this.View.Frame.Size.Width, this.View.Frame.Size.Height);
                this.View.AddSubview(destView);
                (firstViewController).DidMoveToParentViewController (this);
            }

        } else if (segue.Identifier == SegueIdentifierSecond) {
            swapFromViewController (this.ChildViewControllers[0], this.secondViewController);
        }
    }
```